# C# - Looping through pairs and matching

Tags: c#, algorithm, while-loop, streamreader

So I'm stuck on a program where I have a series of pairs that may or may not be able to connect together to form a complete path through the pairs. I need to be able to check if the second item in a pair can match the first item in another pair and so on until there are no pairs left. For example, my pairs might be:

(1,5)
(2,4)
(3,2)
(5,3)
(4,3)

I would need to be able to somehow iterate through the pairs and check if I can get a complete path that travels through each one, based on if the second digit of a pair matches the first digit of the next pair. In this example, the output would be:
 (1,5), (5,3), (3,2), (2,4), (4,3) 
forming a complete match. If a match can't be formed, I need to report a failure. The input is based on a text file. So far I've been able to read the file with a Streamreader and split the pairs based on newline, then iterate through and split each pair into its items based on the comma. I'm pretty much clueless on how to proceed, if anyone has some ideas I would appreciate it.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("inputs.txt");
string line = null;
line = sr.ReadToEnd();
var str = line.Trim().Split('\n');
int length = str.Length;
int index=1;

while (index < length)
{
    var pair = str[index].Split(',');
    var item1 = pair[0];
    var item2 = pair[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to strip the parenthesis - if they are present in your input file. See `string.Trim` method for that.

The brute force approach:

```
public class Pair
{
  public string First;
  public string Second;
}


List<Pair> pairs = new List<Pair>();
for (int index = 0; iter < str.Length; index++)
{
    var pair = str[index].Split(',');
    pairs.Add(new Pair(){First = pair[0], Second = pair[1]});
}

List<Pair> ordered = new List<Pair>();
ordered.Add(pairs[0]);
pairs.RemoveAt(0);

while (pairs.Count > 0)
{
    bool found = false;
    for (int iter = 0; iter < pairs.Count; iter++)
    {
        if (ordered[ordered.Count - 1].Second == pairs[iter].First)
        {
            ordered.Add(pairs[iter]);
            pairs.RemoveAt(iter);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
      <report error>
      break;
    }
}
```

Error checking is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Great, thanks! Looks like I can use this to get my program working. One thing - all my "second" values have "\r" appended to them (due to the pairs being on individual lines of my input file) and thus are never equal to the values in "first" even if the number is the same. Is there a way to trim this return character off of those values before I compare? Thanks again.

Comment: Also, do I want to break when I find the first match? I need to find a path through the entire series, not just after one match is true.

Comment: @noclist - take a look at the `Trim` method of `string`.

Comment: @noclist - About when to break: the code has a `for` loop inside a `while` loop. The `for` loop stops as soon as a suitable item that can be used to continue the ordered path is found. It depends on what you know about the data - if multiple such items are possible, you need to come up with a strategy to pick one of them.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you described can be converted to another form; a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory).

Here's what it looks like for the example you gave.

[image: A directed graph representing your example]

I drew an arrow from 1 to 5 since there was the pair (1,5), etc.

A path on a graph like this can only go the directions of the arrows.

What you want to know is: "is there a path in this graph that uses every pair, i.e. goes over every edge?"

Such a path is known as an [Eulerian Directed Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path)

Wikipedia lists two algorithms for finding such paths, Fleury's and Hierholzer's, both of which were discovered in the late 1800's. Hopefully, this gives you an idea of where to start in solving this problem.

Comment: Very interesting. This got me reading more about graph theory and the "Seven Bridges of Königsberg" that was solved by Euler. I never would have thought a problem like this could be re-imagined as a graph, thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: This is not tested!!

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class t1{
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("inputs.txt");
    string line = null;
    line = sr.ReadToEnd();
    var str = line.Trim().Split('\n');
    int length = str.Length;
    int[][] arr=new int[10][];//[str.Length][2];
    int index=0;

    while (index < length)
    {
        var pair = str[index].Split(',');
        var item1 = Convert.ToInt32(pair[0]);
        var item2 = Convert.ToInt32(pair[1]);
        arr[index]=new int[]{item1,item2};

        index++;
    }

    for (int i=0;i<arr.Length;i++)
    {
        for (int j=i+1;j<arr.Length;j++)
        {
            if  (arr[i][1] == arr[j][0])
            {
                    //MATCH
            }
            else
            {
                    //FAILURE
             }
        }
    }
}
}
```